# My Video/Photo App captures the photo/video in portrait mode even if I have the phono in landscape. Can anyone help me fix that?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avfoundation

First part of the code is the camera configuration and the second part is the view controller.  When I look at the photo I saved in my albums, it shows a portrait video not depending on the orientation of my camera. If my video is in portrait mode, the video/photo will be in portrait as well which is what I want, however, when I record in landscape the file still is in portrait mode. Can someone help me out, that will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class CameraConfiguration: NSObject {

    enum CameraControllerError: Swift.Error {
        case captureSessionAlreadyRunning
        case captureSessionIsMissing
        case inputsAreInvalid
        case invalidOperation
        case noCamerasAvailable
        case unknown
    }

    public enum CameraPosition {
        case front
        case rear
    }

    public enum OutputType {
        case photo
        case video
    }

    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
    var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var rearCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var audioDevice: AVCaptureDevice?

    var currentCameraPosition: CameraPosition?
    var frontCameraInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
    var rearCameraInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var flashMode: AVCaptureDevice.FlashMode = AVCaptureDevice.FlashMode.off
    var photoCaptureCompletionBlock: ((UIImage?, Error?) -> Void)?
    var videoRecordCompletionBlock: ((URL?, Error?) -> Void)?

    var videoFileOutput : AVCaptureMovieFileOutput!

    var videoOutput: AVCaptureMovieFileOutput?
    var audioInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
    var outputType: OutputType?
}

extension CameraConfiguration {

    func setup(handler: @escaping (Error?)-> Void ) {

        func createCaptureSession() {
            self.captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        }

        func configureCaptureDevices() throws {
            let session = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession.init(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)

            let cameras = (session.devices.compactMap{$0})

            for camera in cameras {
                if camera.position == .front {
                    self.frontCamera = camera
                }
                if camera.position == .back {
                    self.rearCamera = camera

                    try camera.lockForConfiguration()
                    camera.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus
                    camera.unlockForConfiguration()
                }
            }
            self.audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.audio)
        }

        //Configure inputs with capture session
        //only allows one camera-based input per capture session at a time.
        func configureDeviceInputs() throws {
            guard let captureSession = self.captureSession else {
                throw CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing
            }


            if let rearCamera = self.rearCamera {
                self.rearCameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: rearCamera)
                if captureSession.canAddInput(self.rearCameraInput!) {
                    captureSession.addInput(self.rearCameraInput!)
                    self.currentCameraPosition = .rear
                } else {
                    throw CameraControllerError.inputsAreInvalid
                }
            }

            else if let frontCamera = self.frontCamera {
                self.frontCameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontCamera)
                if captureSession.canAddInput(self.frontCameraInput!) {
                    captureSession.addInput(self.frontCameraInput!)
                    self.currentCameraPosition = .front
                } else {
                    throw CameraControllerError.inputsAreInvalid
                }
            }

            else {
                throw CameraControllerError.noCamerasAvailable
            }

            if let audioDevice = self.audioDevice {
                self.audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice)
                if captureSession.canAddInput(self.audioInput!) {
                    captureSession.addInput(self.audioInput!)
                } else {
                    throw CameraControllerError.inputsAreInvalid
                }
            }
        }

        //Configure outputs with capture session
        func configurePhotoOutput() throws {
            guard let captureSession = self.captureSession else {
                throw CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing
            }

            self.photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            self.photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.jpeg ])], completionHandler: nil)
            if captureSession.canAddOutput(self.photoOutput!) {
                captureSession.addOutput(self.photoOutput!)
            }
            self.outputType = .photo
            captureSession.startRunning()
        }

        func configureVideoOutput() throws {
            guard let captureSession = self.captureSession else {
                throw CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing
            }

            self.videoOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
            if captureSession.canAddOutput(self.videoOutput!) {
                captureSession.addOutput(self.videoOutput!)
            }



//            let delayTime = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DispatchTime.now()), Int64(5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
//            dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
//                print("stopping")
//                self.movieOutput.stopRecording()
//            }

        }

        DispatchQueue(label: "setup").async {
            do {
                createCaptureSession()
                try configureCaptureDevices()
                try configureDeviceInputs()
                try configurePhotoOutput()
                try configureVideoOutput()
            } catch {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    handler(error)
                }
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                handler(nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func displayPreview(_ view: UIView) throws {
        guard let captureSession = self.captureSession, captureSession.isRunning else { throw CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing }

        self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        self.previewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait

        view.layer.insertSublayer(self.previewLayer!, at: 0)
        self.previewLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width , height: view.frame.height)
    }

    func switchCameras() throws {
        guard let currentCameraPosition = currentCameraPosition, let captureSession = self.captureSession, captureSession.isRunning else { throw CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing }
        captureSession.beginConfiguration()
        let inputs = captureSession.inputs

        func switchToFrontCamera() throws {
            guard let rearCameraInput = self.rearCameraInput, inputs.contains(rearCameraInput),let frontCamera = self.frontCamera else { throw CameraControllerError.invalidOperation }
            captureSession.removeInput(rearCameraInput)
            self.frontCameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontCamera)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(self.frontCameraInput!) {
                captureSession.addInput(self.frontCameraInput!)
                self.currentCameraPosition = .front
            }

            else { throw CameraControllerError.invalidOperation }
        }

        func switchToRearCamera() throws {
            guard let frontCameraInput = self.frontCameraInput, inputs.contains(frontCameraInput), let rearCamera = self.rearCamera else { throw CameraControllerError.invalidOperation }
            captureSession.removeInput(frontCameraInput)
            self.rearCameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: rearCamera)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(rearCameraInput!) {
                captureSession.addInput(rearCameraInput!)
                self.currentCameraPosition = .rear
            }

            else { throw CameraControllerError.invalidOperation }
        }

        switch currentCameraPosition {
        case .front:
            try switchToRearCamera()

        case .rear:
            try switchToFrontCamera()
        }
        captureSession.commitConfiguration()
    }

    func captureImage(completion: @escaping (UIImage?, Error?) -> Void) {
        guard let captureSession = self.captureSession, captureSession.isRunning else {
            completion(nil, CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing)

            return
        }

        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        settings.flashMode = self.flashMode
        self.photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
        self.photoCaptureCompletionBlock = completion


    }

    func recordVideo(completion: @escaping (URL?, Error?)-> Void) {
        guard let captureSession = self.captureSession, captureSession.isRunning else {
            completion(nil, CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing)
            return
        }

        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let fileUrl = paths[0].appendingPathComponent("output.mp4")
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileUrl)
        videoOutput!.startRecording(to: fileUrl, recordingDelegate: self)
        self.videoRecordCompletionBlock = completion
    }

    func stopRecording(completion: @escaping (Error?)->Void) {
        guard let captureSession = self.captureSession, captureSession.isRunning else {
            completion(CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing)
            return
        }
        self.videoOutput?.stopRecording()
    }
}

extension CameraConfiguration: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error { self.photoCaptureCompletionBlock?(nil, error) }
        if let data = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            self.photoCaptureCompletionBlock?(image, nil)
        }
        else {
            self.photoCaptureCompletionBlock?(nil, CameraControllerError.unknown)
        }
    }
    fileprivate func _imageOrientation(forDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation, isMirrored: Bool) -> UIImage.Orientation {

        switch deviceOrientation {
        case .landscapeLeft:
            return isMirrored ? .upMirrored : .up
        case .landscapeRight:
            return isMirrored ? .downMirrored : .down
        default:
            break
        }

        return isMirrored ? .leftMirrored : .right
    }


    func convert(cmage:CIImage) -> UIImage
    {
        let context:CIContext = CIContext.init(options: nil)
        let cgImage:CGImage = context.createCGImage(cmage, from: cmage.extent)!
        let image:UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage)
        return image
    }


}

extension CameraConfiguration: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
        if error == nil {
            self.videoRecordCompletionBlock?(outputFileURL, nil)
        } else {
            self.videoRecordCompletionBlock?(nil, error)
        }
    }
}

extension CameraConfiguration: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

}







import UIKit
import Photos

class CameraViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cameraButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var toggleCameraButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var toggleHelp: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var cameraSelectionButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var videoCameraButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var toggleFlashButton: UIButton!

    var cameraConfig: CameraConfiguration!
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    var videoRecordingStarted: Bool = false 

    func checkPermission(completion: @escaping ()->Void) {
        let photoAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        switch photoAuthorizationStatus {
        case .authorized:
            print("Access is granted by user")
            completion()
        case .notDetermined:
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({
                (newStatus) in
                print("status is \(newStatus)")
                if newStatus ==  PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
                    /* do stuff here */
                    completion()
                    print("success")
                }
            })
            print("It is not determined until now")
        case .restricted:
            // same same
            print("User do not have access to photo album.")
        case .denied:
            // same same
            print("User has denied the permission.")
        default:
            return
        }
    }

    fileprivate func registerNotification() {
        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "App is going background"), object: nil)

        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appCameToForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func appMovedToBackground() {
        if videoRecordingStarted {
            videoRecordingStarted = false
            self.cameraConfig.stopRecording { (error) in
                print(error ?? "Video recording error")
            }
        }
    }

    //@IBAction func gotoGallery(_ sender: Any) {
     //  checkPermission(completion: {
          //  self.imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
          //  self.imagePickerController.delegate = self

          //  self.imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.image", "public.movie"]
           // self.present(self.imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //        })
    //}

    @objc func appCameToForeground() {
        print("app enters foreground")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.cameraSelectionButton.tintColor = UIColor.blue

        self.cameraConfig = CameraConfiguration()

        cameraConfig.setup { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }

        }

        registerNotification()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    }

    @IBAction func toggleFlash(_ sender: Any) {
        if cameraConfig.flashMode == .on {
            cameraConfig.flashMode = .off
            self.toggleFlashButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flash_off"), for: .normal)
        } else if cameraConfig.flashMode == .off {
            cameraConfig.flashMode = .on
            self.toggleFlashButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flash_on"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            cameraConfig.flashMode = .auto
            self.toggleFlashButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flash_auto"), for: .normal)
        }
    }

    @objc fileprivate func showToastForSaved() {
        showToast(message: "Saved!", fontSize: 12.0)
    }

    @objc fileprivate func showToastForRecordingStopped() {
        showToast(message: "Recording Stopped", fontSize: 12.0)
    }

    @objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            // we got back an error!
            showToast(message: "Could not save!! \n\(error)", fontSize: 12)
        } else {
            showToast(message: "Saved", fontSize: 12.0)

        }
    }

    @objc func video(_ video: String, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            // we got back an error!

            showToast(message: "Could not save!! \n\(error)", fontSize: 12)
        } else {
            showToast(message: "Saved", fontSize: 12.0)
        }
        print(video)
    }

    @IBAction func didTapOnTakePhotoButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if self.cameraConfig.outputType == .photo {
            self.cameraConfig.captureImage { (image, error) in
                guard let image = image else {

                    print(error ?? "Image capture error")
                    return
                }

//                try? PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChangesAndWait {
//                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
//                }
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(self.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
            }
        } else {
            if videoRecordingStarted {
                videoRecordingStarted = false
                toggleCameraButton.isHidden = false
                cameraSelectionButton.isHidden = false
                videoCameraButton.isHidden = false
                toggleFlashButton.isHidden = false
                toggleHelp.isHidden = false
                self.cameraConfig.stopRecording { (error) in
                    print(error ?? "Video recording error")
                }
            } else if !videoRecordingStarted {
                toggleCameraButton.isHidden = true
                cameraSelectionButton.isHidden = true
                videoCameraButton.isHidden = true
                toggleFlashButton.isHidden = true
                toggleHelp.isHidden = true
                videoRecordingStarted = true
                self.cameraConfig.recordVideo { (url, error) in
                    guard let url = url else {
                        print(error ?? "Video recording error")
                        return
                    }
                    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(url.path, self, #selector(self.video(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @IBAction func toggleCamera(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
            try cameraConfig.switchCameras()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

       switch cameraConfig.currentCameraPosition {
      case .some(.front):
            self.toggleCameraButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "camera_front"), for: .normal)
        case .some(.rear):
           self.toggleCameraButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "camera_rear"), for: .normal)
        default:            return
       }
    }
    @IBAction func selectVideoMode(_ sender: Any) {
        self.cameraConfig.outputType = .video
        self.cameraSelectionButton.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        self.videoCameraButton.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    }
    @IBAction func selectCameraMode(_ sender: Any) {
        self.cameraConfig.outputType = .photo
        self.videoCameraButton.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        self.cameraSelectionButton.tintColor = UIColor.blue

    }



}


extension CameraViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        if let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL {
            print("videoURL:\(String(describing: videoURL))")
        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Download the AVCam example. Study it. It shows you how to deal with orientation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcam_building_a_camera_app

Comment: Please provide the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which may help others to find out your problem quickly.

Comment: it sounds like to me you aren't detecting if the phone is in landscape or portrait.

Comment: how would I add that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to detect changes in frame size and orientation:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    videoLayer?.frame = view.bounds

    guard let connection = previewLayer?.connection else { return }

    switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
    case .portrait:           connection.videoOrientation = .portrait
    case .portraitUpsideDown: connection.videoOrientation = .portraitUpsideDown
    case .landscapeLeft:      connection.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
    case .landscapeRight:     connection.videoOrientation = .landscapeLeft
    default:                  break
    }

    ...
}
```

If you want, you can update your `photoOutput`, too:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    ...

    if let outputConnection = photoOutput.connection(with: .video) {
        outputConnection.videoOrientation = connection.videoOrientation
    }
}
```